# Where is API call to do "lights out mode" in honeycomb?

Tags: android-3.0-honeycomb, android

I am working on a game and would like to have the full screen to itself.

Did anyone found a way to make the app go full screen on Android Honeycomb preview emulator?

Answer (score 38):

Lights out mode has changed in the full 3.0 SDK.  You can now enter lights out mode as follows:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.view_id);
v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
```

You can also [set](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(android.view.View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener)) a [listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener.html) on the view to be notified on changes to the system bar's visibility.

Comment: Also, a full example is available in the HoneycombGallery example.

Comment: In my experience, this *only* works when `android:minSdkVersion` is >=11.

Comment: just to clarify after my investigation the view you have to use is the top level view in the current activity that fills the screen.

Comment: `targetSdkVersion` has to be `>= 11`. But this has the effect of removing the "Menu" soft-button on my ICS tablet. Aarrgh!

Comment: should use View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE now instead as View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

In prior versions of Android you can set the application to a full screen mode using this line in the manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen".
```

I can't say for sure that works in 2.3, since I haven't done anything with 2.3 yet.

Secondly, I'm not too familiar with the term "lights out mode" but you can adjust the screen brightness using the [`WindowManager.LayoutParams` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html) and the `screenBrightness` field.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I can add:

1. My ListActivity hides the status bar, but when it pops up a progress dialog the status bar shows for as long as the progress dialog is displayed.  The following reduced it to a brief flash, and applies to all dialogs done via "showDialog".  I can't get rid of it entirely yet.

   ```
   protected void onPrepareDialog (int id, Dialog dialog) {
       View main_layout = dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
       main_layout.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
   }
   ```

   CAVEAT: "onPrepareDialog" is deprecated...
2. As shown in the snippet above, you can get the root view's ID without defining an explicit ID in the parent layout in the xml layout file, which makes this a one-file edit.