# MonoDroid on HoneyComb - lights out

Tags: android, api, android-3.0-honeycomb, xamarin.android

I'm developing an Android app using MonoDroid. I'm developing against a Motorola Xoom running Android 3.0 Honeycomb.

It seems that MonoDroid only binds against Android up to 2.3... Not really a problem, my app still runs great on the tablet.

The issue is: Honeycomb displays a status bar along the bottom of the screen, which I can't work out how to hide (my app is a full screen, 'kiosk')

I see the API to use here: [Where is API call to do "lights out mode" in honeycomb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834542/where-is-api-call-to-do-lights-out-mode-in-honeycomb/5097719#5097719)

Unfortunately, it's not available to me in MonoDroid (presumably, because the highest API target I can set is 2.3)

Any way for me to call this function on MonoDroid?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Mono for Android's [JNI support](http://mono-android.net/Documentation/API_Design#Jave_Native_Interface_Support) to invoke methods that aren't currently bound. A quick (and completely untested) "port" to call `setSystemUiVisibility`:

```
View v = FindViewById(R.Id.view_id)
IntPtr View_setSystemUiVisibility = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(v.Class.Handle,
        "setSystemUiVisibility", "(I)V");
// from: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN
int STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN = 1;
JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod(v.Handle, View_setSystemUiVisibility,
        new JValue (STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN));
```