# Hiding Systembar in android 3.0(honeycomb)

Tags: android

How do I hide the system bar in android 3.0(honeycomb)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is API call to do "lights out mode" in honeycomb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834542/where-is-api-call-to-do-lights-out-mode-in-honeycomb)

Answer (score 4):

The systembar cannot be removed (on non-rooted devices). You can go into "lights out mode" which dims it and only shows dots where the buttons are using the following code ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834542/where-is-api-call-to-do-lights-out-mode-in-honeycomb)):

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.view_id);
v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
```

This was also asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109988/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-system-bar-in-android-3-0-its-an-internal-device-and), remember to search first.

Answer (score 2):

I tested some ways to kill system bar:

1. Kill by adb shell: - su; ps, look for com.android.systemui; kill  - success, sys-bar removed.
2. Settings, "Sytem UI" force stop - success, sys-bar removed.
3. Root explorer, delete /system/app/systemui.apk - got circle of error messages "com.android.systemui crashed, blabla...". Reboot, tablet started without system bar, no any errors, so success.
4. My app:
   Code:
   android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.getUidForName("com.android.systemui"));
   failed, as expected, because my app can not kill process started by another app.
5. My app:
   permission - android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES
   Code:
   final Context context =  getApplicationContext();
   servMng = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
   servMng.killBackgroundProcesses("com.android.systemui");
   Failed, no idea why.
6. Run script in my app to execute "ps", look for PID and execute "kill", not tested.

Answer (score 2):

We tinkered around with Honeycomb and found a way to hide and restore the bar, although root is required here. You can find a detailed answer in our [article here](http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=306).

Answer (score 1):

Hiding the systembar in honeycomb can be done with Hide Bar. The home page is at http://ppareit.github.com/HideBar/. The code can be found at https://github.com/ppareit/HideBar.