# hiding the lower system bar on +3.0 android

Tags: java, android, fullscreen

well I'm trying to hide the lower system bar on +3.0 version of android i found this, [Hiding Systembar in android 3.0(honeycomb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099105/hiding-systembar-in-android-3-0honeycomb).

Well this tread was pretty old and 4.0 is even out now so i was hoping there is a way to do this now that don't require the user to root the device.

Comment: you mean he status bar at the BOTTOM of the screen, the one with the android nav and time in.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported. Users need to be able to access the HOME and BACK buttons when they are not available by the device off-screen.

Some Android devices that are running 2.x will get upgraded to 4.0. My understanding is that those devices will not have the bottom system bar, as those devices will have off-screen HOME and BACK buttons. Whether the top portion of the system bar (time, signal strength, notifications) will be removable via things like `Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` remains to be seen -- we will know more once the Nexus S and similar devices get upgraded.