# How to hide Menu bar in android tablet?

Tags: android, tabs, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am Developing an app for(honeycomb)tablet , want a full screen view.how to hide the bar in which containing back button ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be no way of hiding it completely unless you have a rooted device. 
See answer from Romain Guy here: [Is there a way to hide the system bar in Android 3.0? It's an internal device and I'm managing navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109988/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-system-bar-in-android-3-0-its-an-internal-device-an)

However, you can dim it. Making them sort of invisible, instead you see the dots. Using LIGHTS_OUT

```
  View v = findViewById(R.id.view_id);
  v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
```

Reference, answer here: [Hiding Systembar in android 3.0(honeycomb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099105/hiding-systembar-in-android-3-0honeycomb)

Or in other words, search for hide system bar android.

Comment: Thanks :) Its hiding fine, but it is appearing again when I touch on it.

Comment: Yes, but you can also add a listener to listen to the updates of the visibility. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(android.view.View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener.html

Comment: Listen to the visibility and then take appropriate actions. The user might want to use the home button for example.