# How to hide soft touch buttons on devices like Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, uibutton, touch

I have just tried VLC app on Galaxy Nexus. The only problem it has is that the touch buttons (back, home and menù) on galaxy nexus are not hidden like it happens on Youtube app.

How is it possible to control touch buttons behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: You can't hide the System tool bar with out Root.

Discuss here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109988/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-system-bar-in-android-3-0-its-an-internal-device-an

Comment: so how apps like youtube and diceplayer can?

Comment: Youtube app comes with the phone. So may be it has some extra permissions.

Comment: yes but diceplayer is a video player app downloadable from the store that doesn't require root permission.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right, the VLC player does this without root permissions ( on my phone it does ;) ).
I found this on stackoverflow:

[Hide ICS back home task switcher buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469112/hide-ics-back-home-task-switcher-buttons)

Comment: a +1 would really appreciated :)

Comment: I am waiting to set the answer as the correct one...the system forced me to wait some minutes ;-)