# Android Layout does not allow user to pull down notification bar

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I am writing an App using MonoDroid and for some reason I cannot pull down the notification bar from the top of the screen. I am thinking this has to do with my layout, but I am not sure. I also notice that when my App is running I do not have the bar at the top showing the battery, time, signal strength, etc.

So, my question is, what do I need to do to allow the user to pull the notification bar down? And how to show the info at the top of the screen?

Comment: YES!!  That was it... well at least part.  Now, I get the top bar with the battery, etc. and I can pull down the notifications.  However, now I get a second line with the app name. I will look and see what other options can be set there, maybe I need a different one.

Comment: I just needed to do this: @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar Now I can pull the notification bar down and see the status bar at the top... thanks!!

Comment: Glad it worked:) I wrote it up as an answer since it helped answer the Q.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have done something to make your app appear in "Full Screen" mode (this will turn the home, menu and back buttons on the bottom of the screen to dots, and hide the navigation bar.

I believe this is called "lights out mode".  Here is one SO question asking how to turn it on (maybe it will help you turn it off as well):  [Hide ICS back home task switcher buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469112/hide-ics-back-home-task-switcher-buttons)

Comment: I do not want to show the home, menu and back buttons on the bottom... I want to show the battery usage, signal strength, clock, etc, at the TOP of the screen.  Some apps hide it, some show it, but in any case, my real problem is that the user cannot pull down the notification bar.  I was only suggesting that the absence of the top bar may be my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your theme is

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" ?
```

It hides the notification bar. Change to a non-fullscreen theme to make the the notification bar visible.