# Android how to make an activity fullscreen without home button

Tags: android, fullscreen

Some games that I play are full screen without the back and home soft buttons. You have to swipe down to get the buttons to show. How do I implement that in an activity? I figured out how to make it fullscreen, but all it does is get rid of the task & notification bar. The nav buttons were still there. I am using several different devices, so if it matters what OS version is needed, I would appreciate that information too.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469112/hide-ics-back-home-task-switcher-buttons

Comment: You are inquiring about immersive mode I believe.

Comment: Immersive mode is exactly what I was looking for. Resubmit as an answer and I will give you credit.