# System overlay to Disable home button on Android

Tags: android

I am trying to achieve something like this,

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.TwinBlade.PicturePassword

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.free.studio.lockscreen

On Nexus 7, these completely disable the bottom bar, back, home and recent apps button.

I tried using TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, but doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469112/hide-ics-back-home-task-switcher-buttons).

Comment: In these apps, these buttons are shown but disabled. They won't accept any click events, also, notification bar is disabled.