# Hide Navigation Bar Permanently

Tags: android, window, navigationbar, android-homebutton

I've followed this thread to hide Navigation bar:

[Hide ICS back home task switcher buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469112/hide-ics-back-home-task-switcher-buttons)

Works fine when the Activity starts, but whenever I press anywhere on the screen the Navigation bar appears again. I've tried this on an empty Activity without any "views" except the Content View.

How can I hide it throughout the duration of my Activity without having to add some kind of Timer or a Thread to just hide it every millisecond?

It would be great to gain some extra screen size or be able to customize my own Navigation Bar throughout my App.

```
if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH )
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION );
else if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB )
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility( View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that came in a long time when we need to show som content in full screen, bumped the difficulty in being able to hide the status bar on some versions of `Android`:

Finally Google’s latest `Android OS`, `KitKat`, introduces a decent user-friendly tool that gives us ownership of that last bit of screen.

**Using Immersive Full-Screen Mode** see more in : https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

```
// This snippet hides the system bars.
private void hideSystemUI() {
    // Set the IMMERSIVE flag.
    // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the content
    // doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
}

// This snippet shows the system bars. It does this by removing all the flags
// except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
private void showSystemUI() {
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Here's how this has been a thorn in : http://blog.grio.com/2014/02/androids-hiding-of-the-system-bar-fixed.html

Comment: Tried that and the Navigation Bar still appears after interacting with an empty Activity. Only solution I can see is to change it every milisecond if it's changed. Also, not alot of devices have KitKat as a standard yet.

Comment: Any solution for JB & ICS?