# How to disable home button programmatically?

Tags: android

I can't disable my phone's home button.

I'm trying the following but it is not working:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Is it possible to disable the home button within Android?

Comment: You can't disable home button in android.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469112/hide-ics-back-home-task-switcher-buttons

Comment: `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` is for keeping screen on while app is visible.

Comment: Made the question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible, but you can set your app as launcher, then, when home button is clicked your app will be called, keeping your app open.

To make this, add two categories in your main activity.

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```