# How can I disable click event on Home key in android?

Tags: android, click, android-homebutton

I am Using following method to disable **HomeKey** click event ,but after Clicking Home key My App will be closed. I  want ,whenever user click home key my app will not be close.

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
    moveTaskToBack(false);
}
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383469/how-to-disable-home-button-programmatically

Comment: tks  for ur quick response..didn't work tat link @aksacha

Answer (score 1):

> Since Android 4 there is no effective method to deactivate the home
>   button. That is the reason why we need another little hack. In general
>   the idea is to detect when a new application is in foreground and
>   restart your activity immediately.

Check this workaround: http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Override the below method in your Activity,

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);           
}
```

And now handle the key event like this,

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
    {
     Log.i("Home Button","Clicked");
    }
   if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
   {
        finish();
   }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: "TYPE_KEYGUARD" shows error..but i'm using TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG type...This error will be occur  --- **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Window type can not be changed after the window is added**.--

Answer (score 0):

Put his into your activity's code. It will intercept back button click

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can ovverride home button pressed like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the home button!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                     
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```