# Android Lights out mode not working

Tags: android

I just tried it with the 2 lines of code shown here:

[Where is API call to do "lights out mode" in honeycomb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834542/where-is-api-call-to-do-lights-out-mode-in-honeycomb)

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.view_id);
v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
```

And it has no effect for me.

Tried it with several views of my layout. Any Idea what I am doing wrong here? Are there any conditions I have to meet to get the effect I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now I had time to dig a bit deeper and found the problem - I put it here so others can learn from my mistake - the problem was that android:targetSdkVersion was missing in the manifest - I had the right target in project.properties, but that was not enough - with a android:targetSdkVersion="15" lights out works like a charm.